# Expand the value for all similar column above or below in power query

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, conditional-statements, powerquery, calculated-columns

I have a table as follows.

```
      |---------------------|---------------------|    
      |       Name          |         VEC         |          
      |---------------------|---------------------|
      |         A           |        null         |              
      |---------------------|---------------------|
      |         A           |         null        |                
      |---------------------|---------------------|
      |         B           |         null        |                 
      |---------------------|---------------------|
      |         B           |         null        |                
      |---------------------|---------------------|
      |         B_1         |         54          |               
      |---------------------|---------------------|
      |         D           |         null        |                
      |---------------------|---------------------|
      |         D_1         |         null        |               
      |---------------------|---------------------|
      |         E           |         null        |                
      |---------------------|---------------------|
      |         E_1         |         454         |               
      |---------------------|---------------------|
      |         E_2         |         454444      |               
      |---------------------|---------------------|
```

I am trying to produce the following result:

```
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|    
  |       Name          |         VEC         |     Costum          |      
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         A           |        null         |          REF        |        
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         A           |         null        |            REF      |      
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         B           |         null        |           REF       |      
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         B           |         null        |           RUP       |      
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         B_1         |         54          |            RUP      |      
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         D           |         null        |        REF          |                   
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         D_1         |         null        |         REF         |              
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         E           |         null        |          RUP        |              
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         E_1         |         454         |         RUP         |             
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         E_2         |         454444      |          RUP        |               
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
```

In some cases, the letter has value in "VEC" this is thus easily solved with the conditional columns, which check "VEC" and is done.

However, in some cases, the letters repeat themselves such as B followed by "_".
In this case the "_1" (or "_2", "_3"...) will be the only one with a value.

Here the conditional column does not work, because I would need the first occurence of the letter, i.e just the "A" or "B" to get a row with REF or RUP in the "costum" column.

```
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Table1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Name", type text}, {"VEC", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if [VEC] = null then "REF" else "RUP")
in
    #"Added Conditional Column"
```

Comment: Not sure what issue you are actually facing here. As your custom column fully generating based on values in "VEC" column, what dependency on values from column "Name"? Please explain things bit more if possible.

Comment: I am sorry. Only the Name column with "_" will have a value in VEC, if there is one. And I would like to get the mention in my costum column for the letter without the "_" despite the fact Name has no "_".

Comment: Please edit your sample data and output with real scenario. This would help.

Comment: Ho ! I just realized my mistake! Sorry!

Comment: If you fixed the problem, please post the answer, it may help someone in the future

Comment: Hi, not fixed, and I would be glad to have hints or help!

Comment: Hi, I mande a proposal.

Comment: I think you are explaining to much rather than focusing the issue. Just explain logic for your custom column based on input data. This will make things easy to understand.

Comment: I am sorry. I tried explaining myself in an answer that I proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have gained your required output, is fine. I am just adding one more option here using **Power Query** below

**Step-1** Add a Custom Column to your base table as below-

```
if Text.PositionOf([Name],"_") = -1
    then [Name]
else
    Text.Start([Name],Text.PositionOf([Name],"_"))
```

Here is the output-

[image]

**Step-2:** Now duplicate your base table and apply group by on column **Custom** and SUM on column **VEC**. You can right click on the **Custom** column and select Group BY option from the list and configure as below-

[image]

**Step-3**: Add a custom column as below after applying the Group BY and the final result will be as below-

```
if [sum] = null then "REF" else "RUP"
```

[image]

**Step-4:** Now Merge your base table with new table using **Custom** column and after expanding and keeping the colum **custom.1** you will have this below final output-

[image]

Comment: Do you consider that this solution is more elegant than the solution I proposed? Could you share the power query code? Which is most "intensive" in terms of processing effort from Power Query in your opinion?

Comment: That's difficult to say with out measuring the performance with real data. This is just another option with one time Grouping where as your approach probably have more Grouping if I get that correct. All codes are already provided. Just follow the steps one by one and you will get the required output. Please let me know if any step need more details.

Comment: wooo...ok. I am checking it again and trying to apply it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve your requirement using a **Custom Column** and a **Measure** as stated below- (Let your **VEC** column data type is Integer)

Create a **Custom Column** first with this below code-

```
group_name = 

VAR current_row_name = ref_rup[Name]

VAR current_row_group = 
IF(
    FIND("_",current_row_name,1,0) = 0,
    current_row_name,
    LEFT(
        current_row_name,
        FIND("_",current_row_name,1,0) - 1
    )
)

RETURN current_row_group
```

Now create the **Measure** with this below code-

```
ref or rup = 

VAR current_row_name = min(ref_rup[Name])
VAR current_row_group = min(ref_rup[group_name])

VAR current_row_group_sum = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(ref_rup[VEC]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(ref_rup),
        ref_rup[group_name] = current_row_group
    )
)

RETURN IF(current_row_group_sum > 0, "RUP", "REF")
```

Here is your final output-

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you !But it would be via DAX? This is really interesting, although I am interested in the power query way!

Comment: Yes, here everything is with DAX. I will give a try to achive the same using power query Tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution, I think this could potentially be helpful.

It is a bit over the top to my taste, hence if anyone has something better, simpler, more straight to the point I would be really glad to see how it is done.

I use the power query below, first adding a column for VEC, then splitting Name at the "_" andfinally uding "Record.Field" to reproduce something more or less equivalent to a look up.

```
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Name", type text}, {"VEC", Int64.Type}, {"          ", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"          "}), 
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "NUM", each if [VEC] <> null then 1 else 0),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Split Name", each Text.Split ([Name], "_"){0}),
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom2", {"Split Name"}, {{"Name_SUM", each List.Sum([NUM]), type number}}),
   #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "REF or RUP", each Record.Field(#"Grouped Rows1"{[Split Name=[Split Name]]}, "Name_SUM")),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3", "Custom", each if [REF or RUP] <> 0 then "RUP" else "REF")
   in
    #"Added Custom"
```

I hence have the following results afterwards:
[image]